# Java rmi - unable to rebind an RMI address

Tags: java

I have the following structure:

```
someMethod() {
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
    Irrelevant wantToBeBound = new Irrelevant();

    String rmiAddress = "rmi://myPrefix/someIP:port/serviceName";
    Naming.rebind(rmiAddress, wantToBeBound);
}
```

The Irrelevant wantToBeBound was provided for me, so it should be functioning properly.
The `Naming.rebind()` call, however, throws the following `RemoteException`, of which `getMessage()` prints:

```
Connection refused to host: myPrefix; nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

What's the problem?. The semicolon right after myPrefix is really weird, is that a problem? (I cannot change it though.)